# CSS transition only firing on class return React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

What I'm trying to achieve is the navbar on ufc.com

I've got everything I want so far except the CSS transition only works when returning to the original width. So when I scroll down the width snaps to 100% without transition.

Basically I am using a flex display encapsulating my navbar with two spacer divs on the left and right so that the transition expands and shrinks evenly on both sides.

In my React Navbar class I have a scroll event listener which adds a classname to to my nav items.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavItem } from 'reactstrap';
import './Nav.css';

function Nav() {
  let nav = 'nav';
  let spacer = 'spacer';
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState();

  const handleScroll = () => {
    setScrolled(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  });

  if (scrolled > 0) {
    nav = 'nav scrolled';
    spacer = 'spacer scrolled';
  }

  return (
    <div className='nav-container'>
      <div className={spacer} />
      <Navbar className={nav}>
        <div className='items-box'>
          <NavItem className='nav-item'>Projects</NavItem>
          <NavItem className='nav-item'>
            <strong>NAME</strong>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem className='nav-item'>Resume</NavItem>
        </div>
      </Navbar>
      <div className={spacer} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

CSS

```
.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.spacer {
  max-width: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  transition: 0.7s linear;
}
.spacer.scrolled {
  width: 2%;
}

.nav {
  flex: auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  height: 4rem;
  top: 3rem;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.nav.scrolled {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.items-box {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: forestgreen;
}
```

I believe my problem resides within the spacer and spacer.scrolled classes, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add "width" to your transition call; basically you are calling time and type but not what to transition (another call is all but you just want to affect the width if I'm guessing correctly):  transition: 0.7s linear width;

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, I have tried that and still has the same issue.

Comment: I'm only guessing but perhaps you need those classes in the DOM in a style tag (inline) so the browser can call the transitions? This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432867/react-css-transitions

Comment: An even better answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677059/slideup-and-slidedown-animation-using-react-js/40891107#40891107 Fro the looks of things it looks like React needs to control when the css is applied so the transition can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out, I was just going about it the hard way as per usual.
here's my new solution:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavItem } from 'reactstrap';
import './Nav.css';

    function Nav() {
      let nav = 'nav';
      const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState();
    
      const handleScroll = () => {
        setScrolled(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      });
    
      if (scrolled > 0) {
        nav = 'nav scrolled';
      }
    
      return (
        <Navbar className={nav}>
          <div className='items-box'>
            <NavItem className='nav-item'>Projects</NavItem>
            <NavItem className='nav-item'>
              <strong>NAME</strong>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem className='nav-item'>Resume</NavItem>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
      );
    }
    
    export default Nav;
```

CSS

```
.nav {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex: auto;
  width: 60%;
  color: black;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  height: 4rem;
  top: 3rem;

  transition: width 0.7s linear, top 0.1s;
}

.nav.scrolled {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
}

.items-box {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: forestgreen;
}
```

Turns out using position: fixed snaps the navbar to the left pane of the window which makes it expand un-evenly. Just using position sticky and transitioning like so works just perfectly.